# (Roboguide) Fanuc Karel Socket Messaging MSG_CONNECT error with status -1736775297

Tags: karel

In Roboguide, when I try to connect to a server by calling `MSG_CONNECT` it can give a status of -1736775297. Which is not very helpful, since Karel suppose to give 5 digit positive integer error code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to the Client Tag (Menu->Setup->Host Comm->Clients) was set to STATE: DEFINED (per the manual instruction). But I have to set it to STATE: STARTED before it can work.